# How can I build a Java App with GUI and CLI?

Tags: java, swing, command-line, ant

I have to develop a small app to compare automatically generated folders. It must compare the folders, sub-folders and file contents. The problem is that this app needs to be launched either from a user on his computer to manually check for changes, or automatically along with the ANT nightlies. In the first case the results are displayed as a table in the Swing GUI. But in the other case, it must create a file to put the results in (format doesn't matter, XML, CSV, ...).

Anyone got some tips, or a link to a tutorial ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to add some command line option that switches between ui and file export, e.g. `--gui` or `--export=[filename]`. You could use [Apache Commons CLI](http://commons.apache.org/cli/) for that.

Comment: I would rather go the `--export` way, as showing a GUI is often default for graphical OSes. I would also prefer args4j or JCommander (http://jcommander.org/). But conceputally, the reply is perfectly good.

Comment: Yes the `--export` would be needed anyways if you want to specify the target file (format might either be fixed, passed as another parameter or be inferred from the filename). I don't know JCommander, does it provide command line parsing facilities?

Comment: just follow the link :-) As args4j, it provides command line parsing using annotations, which is by far simpler than commons CLI command line construction.

Answer (score 0):

The other method is to create a set of classes that performs the task, and returns a set of values, which can then be either written to disk, or displayed in a GUI. I.e., an engine, and two front-ends (the GUI and the CLI).

for example:

```
public interface DirectoryComparer {
   CompareResult performCompare(Directory dir1, Directory dir2);

   public static interface CompareResult {
      //...things here that you need, such as, file or dir difference, etc
      Iterable<File> getFileDiff();
      Iterable<Directory> getDirectoryDiff();
   }
}
```

then, the GUI clients will just use `DirectoryComparer` to display the results, and the CLI client will write these results to a file or three. But those two clients are completely separate, and can be maintained separately.